# Bad operand types for binary operator '%'

Tags: java, list, java-8

I am trying to code the java 8 way:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int arr [] =  {3,4,5,6,7};

    Arrays.asList(arr)
          .stream()
          .filter(i -> i % 2)
          .sorted()
          .map(j -> j+ 1)
          .forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

`filter` is supposed to pretty much throw away odd numbers but I get the below error.

```
Main.java:16: error: bad operand types for binary operator '%'
              .filter(i -> i % 2)
                             ^
  first type:  int[]
  second type: int
Main.java:18: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
              .map(j -> j+ 1)
                         ^
  first type:  int[]
  second type: int
```

Can someone please explain the cause of this error?

Comment: Do you not need something along the lines of `i -> i % 2 == 0`?

Comment: `i % 2` does not evaluate to a boolean, did you want `i % 2 == 0` or `i % 2 == 1`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your desired code may look like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int arr [] =  {3,4,5,6,7};
    IntStream.of(arr)
          .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
          .sorted()
          .map(j -> j+ 1)
          .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

1. `IntStream` provides a sequence of primitive int-valued elements which seems is what you need. This may be more efficient than boxing the values.
2. The `filter` in this case needs an [int predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntPredicate.html). It should return `true` or `false` as in the example code above. Your lambda is not a predicate because it returns an integer.

Answer (score 14):

You have several errors :

1. `Arrays.asList()` for a primitive array returns a List whose single element is that array. Therefore the elements of your `Stream` are arrays instead of integers. You should change `int arr [] =  {3,4,5,6,7}` to `Integer arr [] =  {3,4,5,6,7}`, in order to get a `List<Integer>`.
2. `filter` takes a Predicate, i.e. a method that returns boolean. Therefore `filter(i -> i % 2)` should be `filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)` (if you want to keep the even numbers) or `filter(i -> i % 2 == 1)` (if you want to keep the odd numbers).

Comment: Or better than using `List<Integer>` create a primitive stream: `IntStream.of(arr).filter(...)`

Comment: this is correct and also adds some context as to the why's :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that  `Arrays.asList(arr)` returns a `List` of array. That is why you are getting the error. `Main.java:16: error: bad operand types for binary operator '%'`